# React - How to define props with typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a demo [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-dzjgqh?file=index.tsx)

It a simple todo app in React using typescript.

I'm trying to define the props in typescript.

I have an interface in the Todo component for the props being passed in

If I try to access text in the Todo component I get an error saying

`Property 'text' does not exist on type 'string'.`

How do I define the props correctly using typescript

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're defining `todo` as a string, but you're using it as an object that contains a `text` property as a string. Therefore, you props definition should be like this:

```
interface IProps {
  index: number,
  todo: { text: string }
}
```

Comment: This creates another error `Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {text, isComplete}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.`

Answer (score 3):

You need to use interface to define your props. Take a look at the example below:

```
import * as React from 'react'    

interface IProps {
   name: string
   isActive?: boolean
}

const MyAwesomeComponent: React.FC<IProps> = ({name, isActive})=> (
    <p>Hello {name}. Your status is {isActive ? 'active': 'inactive'}</p>
)
```

`name` is required but not `isActive`